# How to retrieve messages from inbox in flickr

Tags: php

I want to retrieve messages from inbox in flickr application, please any one suggest me how to retrieve that.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the API reference?
It's rather detailed and even comes with PHP libraries.
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Comment: yes i have checked flickr API reference but there is no such method to retrieve that.